# Customize WCF Rest error responses

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I have written a WCF REST API for third-party use. One of the things I want to do is to return custom error responses to clients if anything goes wrong. I don't want the WCF default error page showing that internal server error has occurred or method name not found.

To do so I throw `WebFaultException<Error>` where necessary. This return the following type of response to the client:

```
<Error>
  <type>MissingTag</type>
  <Desc>Tag 349 is missing</Desc>
</Error>
```

But how can I handle if any other type of error occurs like a serialization error or the "Method not found" error or place where I want to check that POST, PUT and PATCH have http header content-type present. I want to throw `WebFaultException<>` there too. I tried looking into `IErrorHandler` but could not get it working.

Any one got ideas on how to implement this type of thing. Also can I have a simple code demonstrating the `IErrorHandler` usage?

Comment: Have you tried looking into MessageInspectors BeforeSendReply event:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx

Comment: @Rajesh, yes I have. But if POST method has no content-type defined it is not called and the serialization exception remains uncaught.

Comment: I thought that any response either a success or exception occurs the BeforeSendReply event is fired and you can customise your response if needed there. Have you given it a try

Comment: @Rajesh, yes I have. its not called if a SerializationException occurs down the pipeline.

Comment: Are you referring to the serializationException when the request is made? If so then you need to see the AfterRecieveRequest event

Comment: @Rajesh thanks for the hint. Let me go through this and I'll let you know if it works out.

Comment: @Rajest, Thanks it did my work.

Comment: Your welcome. I would post it as an answer for you to mark it so that it would be helpful for others with the same scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) BeforeSendReply for customizing the reply that needs to be sent to the client

If the content-type is not set when the request is made you can look into the AfterReceiveRequest where in you can customise the request received and then action as needed.